# {% if user.is_authenticated %} Always return true

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am just trying to run a simple {% if user.is_authenticated %}. But it always returns true.
what I want to do is to check if the user is logged in. if yes the Dashboard button should appear and if not the Register button should appear.

Can you help me here!

Here are my files:

vews.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth
from django.contrib import messages


# Create your views here.
def login(request):

    return render(request, 'authorisation/login.html', {})


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email'].replace('', '').lower()
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        if not password1 == password2:
            messages.error(request, "Passwords doesn't match")
            return redirect('register')

        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.error(
                request, "A user with the email address : {} already exists, please use a different email".format(email))
            return redirect('register')

        newUser = User.objects.create_user(
            email=email, username=email, password=password2)
        newUser.save()

        auth.login(request, newUser)
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'authorisation/register.html', {})
```

My HTML page :

```
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-primary ml-lg-2" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>

      {% else %}

      <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="btn btn-primary ml-lg-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
      </li>

      {% endif %}
```

**It always returning The *Dashboard***

Comment: Your registration logs the user in. Did you log out meanwhile?

Comment: did your user succesfully log in? you can use the django admin to check if the user is logged in. Also if the user is logged the user `is_authenticated` property will be on request.user object. But first you need to check if you can successfully login via the admin if you are able to login, you can do this instead `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}<button>Logged in</button>{% else %}<button>Register</button>{% endif %}`

Comment: maybe you are login in as ```admin``` , try to ```print(request.user)```